# Take a vocabulary from a txt file in c

Tags: c, arrays

i have an assignment where i have to extract the respective morse code per word that is stored in a text file. it's a word and it's code per line so i save the whole line and try to separate the string as: `Y = ..-`.

```
char letter;
char meaning[30][30];
char letters[30];
while(i<30){
    int i =0;
    gets(code,10,fPointer);
    //i save the position 0 in the char array because the letter is always is the 1st position
    letter = code[0];
    letters[i]= letter;
    i++;

    int S = strlen(code);
    for(int f=3;f<=N;f++){
        //i need to save the rest of the line in a different array but i don't know how}
```

i'm new to programming so i don't really know too many functions so ideas on how to solve them or new functions will be welcome

basically i know how to take the whole line and put it in an array, the first position i save it as it is the letter and the rest i don't know how to separate it

i want 2 arrays

```
array1[30] = "a" ,"b", "c",
array2[30][30] = ".--", "..-",
```

so a and it's code are both in the position 0 and all the other letters

Comment: You're not calling `gets()` correctly. You're calling it with the arguments for `fgets()`, which is the appropriate function to use.

Comment: Why does the `for` loop start at `f=3`? And what is `N`, should that be `S`?

Comment: i am using fgets, that was a mistake. my program does save the lines on the string array "code" i just don't know how to separate the individual characters, i've tried for loops to save them on a different array but it doesn't work, the characters start at the position 3 because before it's the letter, a space, the equal sign, another space and then the code and yes it's S, my bad haven't got much sleep

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `strcpy()` to copy the rest of the line to `meanings[i]`.

You shouldn't initialize `i = 0;` inside the loop, since then it will never reach `30`. And you shouldn't increment `i` until after you copy to `meanings[i]`. You can use a `for` loop instead of `while` to simplify all of this.

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    char *res = fgets(code,10,fPointer);
    if (!res) { // EOF or error
        break;
    }
    //i save the position 0 in the char array because the letter is always is the 1st position
    letter = code[0];
    letters[i]= letter;

    int S = strlen(code);
    if (code[S-1] == '\n') { // trim newline
        code[S-1] = '\0';
    }
    strcpy(meaning[i], &code[4]);
}
```

You can also use `sscanf()` to extract parts of the line.

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    char *res = fgets(code,10,fPointer);
    if (!res) { // EOF or error
        break;
    }
    if (sscanf(code, "%c = %s", &letters[i], meaning[i]) != 2) {
        break; // line isn't formatted correctly
    }
}
```